# Unable to read @Html.TextArea using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have tried many things but I am unable to assign the value to `@Html.TextArea` using the jquery.

I tried

```
$("#taeditor").attr("value", "testing");
$("#taeditor").val("testing");
$("#taeditor").html("testing");
```

but nothing works, kindly help if have any clue.

Comment: provide your rendered html in your question please

Comment: Can you show the code for `@Html.TextArea`

Comment: I'm gonna bet you're using the incorrect ID... Try `$("textarea").val("test data text");`. If that doesn't work, jQuery has either not been loaded, or has not the code has not been wrapped in a [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: here is the rendered html @Html.TextArea("page", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "ckeditor", onchange = "return this;", @id= "taeditor"})

Comment: I saw that when I assign the class ckeditor, it is doing the problem. Now ckeditor is basically converting the textaria with additional formatting controls.

Comment: Use Firefox/Chrome dev tools, inspect the rendered element, and post the html here.

Answer (score 2):

You will need something like...

```
@Html.TextArea("Textarea", new { id = "testing"})
```

and then use...

```
$("#testing").val();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer this works though but ckeditor class is doing problem with my textaria